How to use a custom OCR implementation with tika?
I know tika supports tesseract ocr. I want to use my own custom ocr library with tika instead of tesseract. How to achieve this?
I also want to use the custom library for pdf parsing too as per tika's auto ocr-strategy
I came across this wiki which describes how to use tesseract with tika but i find no instructions on how to replace it with other custom ocr library of our choice.
(I am currently using tika as jar and not as tika server; if that is relevant)
